# Herokuにデプロイ後Stripeを稼働するとInternetError 500 エラーになる

Tags: python, django, heroku

#### 起こっていること

Djangoでアプリを開発しています。ローカル環境ではサブスクサービスStripeは稼働していたのですが、Herokuにデプロイ後 "ServerError 500" が表示されます。

#### 実行したこと

Herokuの環境変数は何度も見直しましたが問題なしです。

settings.pyの一部

```
    if "STRIPE_PUBLISHABLE_KEY" in os.environ and "STRIPE_API_KEY" in os.environ and "STRIPE_PRICE_ID" in os.environ:
    STRIPE_PUBLISHABLE_KEY  = os.environ["STRIPE_PUBLISHABLE_KEY"]
    STRIPE_API_KEY          = os.environ["STRIPE_API_KEY"]
    STRIPE_PRICE_ID         = os.environ["STRIPE_PRICE_ID"]

 - CheckoutView
stripe.api_key  = settings.STRIPE_API_KEY

class CheckoutView(LoginRequiredMixin,View):
    def post(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        checkout_session =stripe.checkout.Session.create(
            line_items=[
                {
                    'price':settings.STRIPE_PRICE_ID,
                    'quantity':1,
                },
            ],
            payment_method_types=['card'],
            mode='subscription',
            success_url=request.build_absolute_uri(reverse_lazy("nagoyameshi:success")) + '?session_id={CHECKOUT_SESSION_ID}',
            cancel_url=request.build_absolute_uri(reverse_lazy("nagoyameshi:index")),
        )

print( checkout_session["id"] )
return redirect(checkout_session.url)

checkout    = CheckoutView.as_view()
```

Comment: Heroku上へデプロイしたアプリで"ServerError"となるのであれば、管理コンソールから確認できるであろうログを一度確認してみてはどうでしょう。すでに出力されているログ上に明確な問題箇所が提示されているかもしれません。もし、ログの内容を見ても解決が難しい場合は、質問を編集してログを追記してみてください。質問の情報量が増えるため、回答などが付きやすくなるかもしれません。

Comment: @attakei さん　ありがとうございます。ログを見たもののわからずこちらに質問いたしましたが、viewの内容を少し修正したことで解決しました、お手数おかけしました！

Comment: 解決できたようで良かったです。可能であれば、修正内容（+原因）を自己回答の形式で投稿したうえで解決としてみてください。似たような観点で困っている人が現れた際のヒントとして役立たせることができます。※[参考](https://ja.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/2634/%e8%b3%aa%e5%95%8f%e3%82%92%e8%87%aa%e5%88%86%e3%81%8b%e3%82%89%e7%b5%82%e4%ba%86%e3%81%97%e3%81%9f%e3%81%84%e5%a0%b4%e5%90%88%e3%81%ab%e3%81%af/2635#2635)

Comment: @attakei さん　実は解決のカギになった修正内容は把握してるのですが、それでなぜ解決できたか不明なので、明確にわかっらた記載しますね。ありがとうございます